# Lag after vuetify `v-icon` visibility changed by css rule

Tags: html, css, vuetify.js

I have a table in a Vue app that is using vuetify. I created a CSS selector to show an icon for `tr:hover` state but there is a delay in hiding the icon when the mouse leaves the row. It only happens with icons (last three rows), any other element (first three rows) shows and disappears as expected. ([here is the codepen](https://codepen.io/gulyamani/pen/vYYpYoP))

Screenshot (more than one icon visible in the first column as the cursor moves up from the bottom):

[image: More than one icon visible]

```css
tr:hover .hover {
  visibility: visible;
}

.hover {
  visibility: hidden;
}

// ...
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <div class="container">
      <table class="center" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td> <span class="hover">A</span></td>
          <td> Row </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> <span class="hover">A</span></td>
          <td> Row </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> <span class="hover">A</span></td>
          <td> Row </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <v-icon class="hover">create</v-icon>
          </td>
          <td> Row </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <v-icon class="hover">create</v-icon>
          </td>
          <td> Row </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <v-icon class="hover">create</v-icon>
          </td>
          <td> Row </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your CSS:

```css
i.hover {
  transition: none;
}
```

The delay is caused by `v-icon` adding `tranistion: .3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.5,1);` which defaults to `transition-property: all`. This, therefore, causes the `.3s` delay on `visibility`.